# SQL1397N - The DB2 service failed to logon

Tags: database

I have IBM Db2 10.5.8 on Win10 - I've been using it for many months.

Today, I start the DB2 Command Line Processor and issue the *db2start* command and I get this error message:  SQL1397N   The DB2 service failed to logon.

I google, and find out this [explanation of the error](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic4.html#sql1397n).  I thought maybe the credentials expired for my db2inst local userid, so I check them, I can login to that account with no issues.

I run *db2admin setid db2inst mypass* just to be sure - no luck.

Stumped, no idea why it fails to login?!  Some kind of post vacation syndrome.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have already solved this problem but this [link](https://it.toolbox.com/question/unable-to-start-db2-express-edition-on-xp-050206) helped me.

Change the password for db2admin in setings-->control panel-->administrative tools-->computer management-->users  then reboot your computer.

Also, go to Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools\services and update password for DB2 service (i.e DB2 - DB2COPY1 - DB2-0). It's on "Log On" tab.

Other cause might be that you need to activate your db2 license.

Answer (score 1):

Go to local and users groups (lusrmgr.msc)
On Users browse db2admin click properties and
Uncheck Account is disabled click ok
then run db2start

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESkI7.png